# ¿Como ejecutar código PHP dentro de una etiqueta HTML?

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<select name="Nivel">
 <option value="Principiante" <?php echo $alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Principiante' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Principiante</option>
 <option value="Medio" <?php echo $alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Medio' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Medio</option>
 <option value="Avanzado" <?php echo $alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Avanzado' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Avanzado</option>
 <option value="Experto" <?php echo $alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Experto' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Experto</option>
</select>
```

Y quiero imprimir la etiqueta `<option>` con una propiedad obtenida en PHP, pero no funciona ya la etiqueta `<?php  ?>` se encuentra ***dentro*** de una etiqueta HTML.

Para poner un ejemplo, lo que intento hacer sería igual a lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($fila as $indice=>$valor) {
    if ($indice == 'idedit') {
        echo'<option value='.$valor.' <?php echo $alm->__GET("Nivel") == "Principiante" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >';
    } elseif ($indice == 'editorial') {
        echo "$valor</option>";
    }
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de imprimir la etiqueta `<option>` con código PHP ejecutado dentro de ésta?

Comment: Si no te funciona "la etiqueta" <?php ?> es porque tu archivo no es un .php (Iba a ponerlo en comentarios, pero no me deja todavía)

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es correcto pero faltan los paréntesis en la parte inicial del if de una línea.

```
<select name="Nivel">
 <option value="Principiante" <?php echo ($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Principiante') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Principiante</option>
 <option value="Medio" <?php echo ($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Medio') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Medio</option>
 <option value="Avanzado" <?php echo ($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Avanzado') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Avanzado</option>
 <option value="Experto" <?php echo ($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Experto') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Experto</option>
</select>
```

Te pongo otra manera de hacer lo mismo pero más corta

`<?=` equivale a abrir código php y hacer un echo. Como puedes ver es bastante útil para casos como este ;-)

```
<select name="Nivel">
 <option value="Principiante" <?=($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Principiante') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Principiante</option>
 <option value="Medio" <?=($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Medio') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Medio</option>
 <option value="Avanzado" <?=($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Avanzado') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Avanzado</option>
 <option value="Experto" <?=($alm->__GET('Nivel') == 'Experto') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Experto</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un if nuevamente en la lógica:

```html
foreach ($fila as $indice=>$valor) {
 if ($indice == 'idedit') {
   if($alm->__GET("Nivel") == "Principiante"){
  echo'<option value="'.$valor.'Principiante">';
   }else{
  echo '<option value="'.$valor.'>';
   }
 } elseif ($indice == 'editorial') {
  echo $valor."</option>";
 }
}
```